# How to keep window always on top / floating in Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

In Leopard there was WindowShade X and Afloat - both great tools.
I dearly miss the feature to keep certain windows on top of everthing.

If anybody knows a workaround please tell me.

But
… I don’t want to set my whole System Preferences in 32bit mode.
… don’t want to use SIMBLE since I need the feature also on 64bit apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still use Afloat - seems to work fine...

I'm using the newest SIMBL that works on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

The Plugsuit prefpane included with Afloat is buggy - and will keep asking for you to authenticate. However by downloading the latest Snow-Leopard compatible SIMBL from [here](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php), and removing PlugSuit from ~/Library/PreferencePanes, Afloat seems to work fine. Hooray - Quicktime movies Always On Top!

Answer (score 0):

Link to a more detailed "how to" blogpost, seems to work perfectly on Safari (which is a 64-bit application on snow leopard): [always on top in snow leopard](http://wickedjv.blogspot.com/2009/09/mac-tip-always-on-top-in-quicktime-on.html)